# PayPal REST API - go to live mode with PHP and curl

Tags: php, api, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I’m developing an online shop using Paypal REST API for payment. 
All works fine in sandbox mode but when I try go in live I get this message :

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}
```

I changed the authentication url to : https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token I changed the client ID and the secret ID to the live ones too.

Is there something else to do in the dashboard to set my account in live mode ?

I’m using curl in my code.

```
    protected $mode = 'PROD'; 

    function getNewToken()
    {
        $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"; 

        if ($this->mode == 'PROD')
            $url = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";

        $token = new ModelAPIToken();
        $token->set('app', 'test-paypal');

        if ($this->mode == 'PROD')
            $token->set('app', 'prod-paypal');

        $token->select();

        $data = 'grant_type=client_credentials'; 

        $curlManager = new Curl();
        $curlManager->setUrl($url); 
        $curlManager->addToHttpHeader('Accept-Language: en_US');
        $curlManager->setCurlOpt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $token->get('user_key') . ":" . $token->get('user_secret')); 
        $curlManager->execute($data); 
        $response = $curlManager->getResponse();

        preg_match('#"access_token":"(.*)","token_type"#', $response, $match);
        $access_token = $match[1];
        $token->set('access_token', $access_token);
        $token->save();
    }
```

Comment: Have you enabled live environment on your developer dashboard / Your App? Sign in to your developer account and click 'My App & Credientials' then click the 'Live' button.

Comment: There is the 'live' button, but it can't be clicked. I tried with Safari and Chrome.

Comment: contact your paypal it support.
I think your account has not been **activated** yet!!

Comment: I did it several hours ago. No answer for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Rest APIs are not available for Live Mode, even though you see them on your dashboard. Even if you click the account eligibility link when you click the the LIVE button you will not be able to apply at all. REST APIs have been pulled for public use. There should be a reference to contact to request eligibility; if not, submit a ticket to merchant technical support team and ask for REST APIs paypal-techsupport.com

Comment: Thanks for the information. I contacted them several hours ago. No answer for the moment. Is there similar payment service working in Europa that I can integrate ?

Comment: A similar one would be Braintree payments. https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/braintree-in-europe-and-canada/

Comment: In reviewing your last comment if you're in Europe you 'should have rest onboarding' options because you might be able to use PayPal Plus- europe payment method for PayPal which uses REST https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf